# How can I remove hashes from my array?

Tags: arrays, ruby, hash

I have an array of hashes

```
@employee_list = [{"id" => 375, "emp_name" => "emp1", "emp_no" => "e1"}, 
                  {"id" => 330, "emp_name" => "emp2", "emp_no" => "e2"}, 
                  {"id" => 38,  "emp_name" => "emp3", "emp_no" => "e3"},
                  {"id" => 49,  "emp_name" => "emp4", "emp_no" => "e4"}]
```

I want to filter it by removing the hashes whose `"id"` value is included in:

```
@not_active_emp = ["49", "375"]
```

to get:

```
@employee_list = [{"id" => 330, "emp_name" => "emp2", "emp_no" => "e2"},
                  {"id" => 38,  "emp_name" => "emp3", "emp_no" => "e3"}]
```

Comment: What did you try so far?

Comment: Take a look at `Enumerable#reject`

Comment: I have tried reject like 
@employee_list.each do |a|
  a.reject {|k,v| v ==  not_active_emp[0]}
end
but it reject only that 'id' not that id's full hash

Comment: Note that `"49"` and `49` are not equal in Ruby.

Comment: The logic is not clear. Why is the one with `"id"` = `357` deleted?

Comment: @sawa "375", "357"... it's a typo.

Comment: @MarcTarin Why can you be sure?

Comment: @sawa Ockham's razor, mere supposition, observation, experience, powers of deduction, imagination, a total lack of humility... pick  your choice :)

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`Array#reject`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.0/Array.html#method-i-reject). The general idea is as follows.

```
@not_active_emp = [49, 375]
@employee_list = [{"id" => 375, "emp_name" => "emp1", "emp_no" => "e1"}, 
                  {"id" => 330, "emp_name" => "emp2", "emp_no" => "e2"}, 
                  {"id" => 38,  "emp_name" => "emp3", "emp_no" => "e3"},
                  {"id" => 49,  "emp_name" => "emp4", "emp_no" => "e4"}]

@employee_list.reject { |hash| @not_active_emp.include? hash['id'] } 
  # => [{"id" => 330, "emp_name" => "emp2", "emp_no" => "e2"},
  #     {"id" => 38,  "emp_name" => "emp3", "emp_no" => "e3"}]
```

Comment: You are answering a different question. Not only the `@not_active_emp`, but also the `@employee_list` is different.

Comment: @sawa There's a certain amount of sensible 'auto-correct' on my part. Since I've stated the updated-array in my answer and used this for my solution I think it's okay. OP seems happy and it's the general idea here that's most important I hope.